# Reopen a pull request on Github

Tags: github, pull-request

I am facing problem on how to reopen a pull request that I accidentally closed on Github. I searched for other people's question and the answers are mostly to use the reopen button, but that does not work for me. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can't you just resubmit the pull request?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to re-open the pull request then there is a button at bottom in git hub
saying **Reopen pull request** . Press that button and you will get your pull request is in open state.

Answer (score 2):

The "Reopen pull request" button will be disabled if you don't have the necessary permissions or if the last commit in the branch is not the exact one that was there when the pull request was closed.

In the later case,

```
git co <branch>
git tag my-bookmark
git reset --hard <commit>
git push --force
```

will allow you to use that button.

Then use

```
git reset --hard my-bookmark
git tag -d my-bookmark
git push --force
```

to get back where you were.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna guess is that you closed a PR (Pull Request) issued by you on a repository that you do not own. In this case, you need to contact with someone that has access to that repository in order to reopen that PR.

If that is not the case, then maybe you came across with a bug and you should report the behavior on GitHub.